# part of speech of 'hardest' here

Tags: parts-of-speech, superlatives

This is from [a webpage](https://www.ycs.wednet.edu/cms/lib6/WA01001221/Centricity/ModuleInstance/955/example_topic_sentences.doc) :

> According to Harper Lee’s novel, *To Kill a Mockingbird*, courage is
> trying your **hardest** even if you know you have no chance of succeeding,
> making the right choice despite the potential consequences, and facing
> your fears.

I wonder what part of speech '**hardest**' is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's at least two perspectives on this.

According to the ESL teaching world, "hardest" must be a noun because of the possessive adjective ("your") before it, which is always followed by a noun.

Also, the structure *[ possessive adjective + superlative ]* can take many noun phrase roles:

> **Your best** just isn't good enough. (subject)
> Do **your worst**. (direct object)
> I went from **my fastest** to **my slowest**. (object of preposition)

The other perspective is from academic Linguistics, which I know less about, but you can find an expert opinion [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/151595).

Comment: Thank you very much.